# Poles of induction motor rotor

Tags: motor, power-electronics, three-phase, motor-controller, induction-motor

For a three phase squirrel cage induction motor (IM,) we can have 2 or 4 or 6 etc. pole pairs on its stator and when these stator windings are energized by 3 phase mains supply then we get a rotating flux inside the motor.

Can we say the same for the rotor of a squirrel cage  IM also?

Please correct me if I am wrong that the rotor of an IM always has 2 poles regardless of the poles on its stator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Induction motors have an even number of poles or any number of pole pairs formed on the stator by the winding pattern. The stator field induces currents in the rotor that form a matching number of poles on the rotor.

Answer (score 3):

In general parlance, an Induction Motor ***IS*** a "Squirrel Cage" Induction Motor (SCIM) unless otherwise specifically referred to as a "Wound Rotor Induction Motor" (WRIM). An SCIM does **not** have windings on the rotor at all, so there are no "poles" in the design, there are rotor bars connected together with end rings, hence the term "squirrel cage".

[image]

There will be ***magnetic*** poles created in the rotor by the stator poles, so they will match whatever is in the stator. But we don't refer to the rotor design as having "poles".

A WRIM on the other hand has windings on the rotor and for it to work, the numer of rotor poles must match the stator poles.